# Uniformly equivalent metrics and the metric on a countable product space

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Two metrics $d_1, d_2$ on a set $X$ are called uniformly equivalent, iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that
$$
 d_1(x,y) < \delta_1 \Rightarrow d_2(x,y) < \varepsilon \quad \textrm{ and } \quad 
 d_2(x,y) < \delta_2 \Rightarrow d_2(x,y) < \varepsilon.
$$
Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of metrizable spaces and let $\rho_i$ be a metric on the space $X_i$ bounded by $1$ for $i = 1,2, \ldots$ (which could always so choosen). Consider the set $X = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$ and for every pair of points $x = \{ x_i \}$ and $y = \{ y_i \}$ let
$$
 \rho(x,y) := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \rho_i(x_i, y_i).
$$
Now I want to show:

If for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$ metrics $\rho_i$ and $\sigma_i$ on a set $X_i$ are uniformly equivalent and bounded by $1$, then the metrics $\rho$ and $\sigma$ on $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i$, as defined above, are also uniformly equivalent.

I don't know how to find an appropriate $\delta_1, \delta_2$ such that the implications hold, cause I don't know if for a sequence something like
$$
 \sum a_i < \delta
$$
what could be said about the individuel elements (besides $a_i < \delta$), the factor $1/2^i$ makes it more difficult for me too... any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our goal is to choose $\delta$ so that $\rho(x,y)<\delta\Rightarrow\sigma(x,y)<\epsilon$.

For any $\epsilon>0$: for each $i$, we may choose $\delta_i$ so that 
$$
\rho_i(x_i,y_i)<\delta_i \Rightarrow \sigma_i(x_i,y_i)<\epsilon/2
$$
In addition, there must be some $k$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty \frac1{2^i} = \frac1{2^k}<\epsilon
$$
(in particular, we may choose $k\in\mathbb Z$ so that $k>-\log_2(\epsilon)$).

Now, consider the set $\delta_1,\delta_2,\dots,\delta_k$ with $\delta_i$ as described above and let $\delta = 2^{-k}\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\dots,\delta_k\}$.  What now?

Comment: thanks, can you pls look at my post if my solutions are valid, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $\rho_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are two equivalent metrics on $X_i$ (one pair for each $i$), and let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be defined as in the question.

Take $\epsilon > 0$. We want to prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $\rho(x,y) < \delta, \sigma(x,y) < \epsilon.$

Pick $N$ sufficiently large such that $\sum_{i=N}^\infty 2^{-i} < \epsilon / 2 .$ Also, (for $1 \leq i < N$) let  $\delta_i$ be such that whenever $\rho_i(x_i,y_i) < \delta_i, \sigma_i(x_i,y_i) < \epsilon / 2.$

Now take $$\delta = 2^{-N} \min_{1 \leq i < N} \delta_i $$

Do you understand why this $\delta$ is good? If $\rho(x,y) < \delta$, what can be said about $\rho_i(x_i, y_i)$ for $1 \leq i < N$?

Hope this gets you on the right track.

Comment: thanks, can you pls look at my post if my solutions are valid, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, while working through your hints I came up with another solution, can you please look over it if it's valid?

**1. My solution**

For every $i = 1,2,\ldots$ choose $\delta_i$ such that
$$
 \rho_i(x,y) < \delta_i \Rightarrow \sigma_i(x,y) < \varepsilon.
$$
and sucht that $0 \le \delta_i \le 1$, which could be done because every $\rho_i$ is bounded by $1$.

Set $\delta := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \delta_i$, then if $\rho(x,y) < \delta$ if follows that
$$
 \rho(x,y) < \delta_i / 2^i
$$
which yields $\rho_i(x,y) < \delta_i$ for each $i$, and so 
$$
 \sigma_i(x,y) < \varepsilon
$$
for each $i$. Now
\begin{align*}
 \sigma(x,y) & = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \sigma_i(x,y) \\
             & = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \varepsilon \\
             & = \varepsilon \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \\
             & = \varepsilon \cdot 1.
\end{align*}
Is this okay?

**2. Based on your hints** (Notation like in Omnomnomnom's post)

If $\rho(x,y) < \delta$, then for $i = 1, \ldots, k$
$$
  \rho(x,y) < \frac{1}{2^k} \min\{ \delta_1, \ldots, \delta_k \} < \frac{1}{2^i} \delta_i. 
$$
So that for $i = 1, \ldots, k$  it holds that $\rho_i(x,y)  < \delta_i$, and so $\sigma_i(x,y) < \varepsilon / 2$. Now
\begin{align*}
 \sigma(x,y) & = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \sigma_i(x,y) \\
             & = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{2^i} \sigma_i(x,y) + \sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \sigma_i(x,y) \\
             & \le \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{2^i} \varepsilon/2 + 2^{-k} \\
             & \le \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon = \frac{3}{2} \varepsilon.
\end{align*}

Comment: For your proof, how do you get from $\rho(x,y)<\delta$ to $\rho(x,y)<\delta_i/2^i$?  For the hint-based proof... I meant to choose $k$ so that the second term would be an $\epsilon/2$, giving you $\epsilon$ at the end. Besides that aesthetic issue, the proof seems fine.

Comment: Your right, that's not a valid step... don't know why I thought so.

Comment: Looks good: $$\rho(x,y) < \frac{1}{2^k} \min\{\delta_1, \ldots, \delta_k\} \leq \frac{1}{2^k} \delta_i \leq \frac{1}{2^i} \delta_i$$ if $i \leq k$.